# Any statistics on how often a 'you have not voted on a question recently' reminder generates an up-vote for the question being looked at?

Tags: discussion, voting, popups, reminder

Has any analysis been done of how often the "you have not voted on a question recently" reminder generates an up-vote for the question being viewed at the time?

I've a suspicion that the correlation would be strong; when the reminder appears, that question is the one that gets a vote.

Comment: Alternatively, a study could be done on how often a user who sees that pop-up notification posts a sharply-worded criticism on Meta tagged as `[bug]`.

Comment: Also, [feature-request] how can I get this reminder to pop up on my questions every time

Comment: I'm guilty of this

Comment: Does this feature still exist? I have never seen this kind of reminder.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe: at least until recently. I don't get it very often; I'm making an effort to up vote more questions but it can be hard.